# $x = \sin \theta, y = \cos \theta, \pi \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ to rectangular

Tags: solution-verification, parametric

Given $x = \sin \theta, y = \cos \theta, \pi \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, a) Eliminate the parameter to find the rectangular equation of the curve; b) Sketch the curve and indicate with an arrow the direction in which the curve is traced as the parameter increases.

Is my work below correct?

a) Based on Pythagorean trig identity, $\sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} = 1$, $x^2+y^2=1$.

b) Attached is my picture.
[solution for B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCd0A.jpg)

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Your curve appears to be going from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma The $x,y$ are flipped from what they normally are

Comment: @AmejiB. Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

The curve is $x^2 + y^2 = 1, x \leq 0$. Without the restriction you get the entire circle, but you just want a semicircle. Alternatively, $x = -\sqrt{1 - y^2}$.

Comment: I just noticed that $x = \sin\theta$, not $\cos \theta$. Sorry about that.